# Find truncation point for top 10% in density plot 

Tags: r, graphics

I want to shade the region where top 10% are localized. I just arbitrary put truncation point 65, to just plot this plot. That is what I intend to find...for every data sets.

```
xf <- rnorm(40000, 50, 10);
plot(density(xf),xlim=c(0,100), main = paste(names(xf), "distribution"))
dens <- density(xf)
x1 <- min(which(dens$x >= 65)) # I want identify this point such that 
# the shaded region includes top 10%

x2 <- max(which(dens$x <  max(dens$x)))
with(dens, polygon(x=c(x[c(x1,x1:x2,x2)]), y= c(0, y[x1:x2], 0), col="green"))
abline(v= mean(traitF2),  col = "black", lty = 1, lwd =2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `quantile()` function:

```
xf <- rnorm(40000, 50, 10)
plot(density(xf),xlim=c(0,100), main = paste(names(xf), "distribution"))
dens <- density(xf)
x1 <- min(which(dens$x >= quantile(xf, .90))) # quantile() ftw!

x2 <- max(which(dens$x <  max(dens$x)))
with(dens, polygon(x=c(x[c(x1,x1:x2,x2)]), y= c(0, y[x1:x2], 0), col="green"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the quantiles. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile

Comment: thank you for help...however as this seems a great comment not answer please improve it as an answer ...right cost some of my reputation, just kidding

Comment: The question seems to be a perfect question to google if you just know what you are looking for, therefore my short answer...

Comment: @John ,the downvote IMO is quite harsh. What you are asking for is the quantiles/percentiles of the distribution. It should not be necessary to provide a complete programmatic implementation to answer your question.

Comment: I think the downvote could be justified on the grounds that a link to Wikipedia is not as useful as a link to an R-function "quantile".

Comment: I do have appreciation for help from Niclas, however it is down voted...instantly....I do not think it deserves so then I began to suspect it is a comment not answer as the answer provides statistical clue not programming clue ....anyway both are same to me...thanks again

Comment: @AndyW: I'm not sure, but based on the conversation here it seems as though John was not the one who gave the downvote ... I agree that a downvote seems harsh -- based on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers it doesn't deserve it

Comment: I can't add much that's not already in Ben's meta. link, but I guess psychologically people get much more upset over a negative rating than a smaller-than-average positive rating, even though the "zero point" in the scale is pretty much arbitrary.